# Yii2: Preventing a specific CSS file from getting loaded

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I need to stop loading the `bootstrap.css` file in one view to void duplicate. But I don't know how to do that in Yii2.

I used  this function in Yii 1:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->scriptMap = array(
    'main.css' => false
);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Yii2 How to prevent autoloading of assetsbundle of any widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29052194/yii2-how-to-prevent-autoloading-of-assetsbundle-of-any-widget)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to disable the `CSS` specific to core bootstrap in a view then add the following on top of your view file like this

```
Yii::$app->assetManager->bundles['yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset'] = false;
```

and if you need to disable the bootstrap core `js` sources also then use

```
Yii::$app->assetManager->bundles['yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset'] = false;
```